# Chart.js line chart overlapping lines solution

Tags: chart.js

I need to display some data on a line chart. There are 3 datasets (value range from 0 to 4). The problem is that the values of the 3 datasets are the same so the lines are overlapping.

```
var ctx = $("#myChart");

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels:  ["11/05/2019", "21/05/2019"],
                datasets: [
                    {
                        label: 'Action 1',
                        backgroundColor: '#B22222',
                        borderColor: '#B22222',
                        //backgroundColor: myColors_act1,
                        data: [0,0],
                        fill: false,
                        pointRadius: 5,
                        pointHoverRadius: 10,
                        showLine: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Action 2',
                        backgroundColor: '#043947',
                        borderColor: '#043947',
                        //backgroundColor: myColors_act2,
                        data: [0,0],
                        fill: false,
                        pointRadius: 5,
                        pointHoverRadius: 10,
                        showLine: true
                    },
                    {
                        label: 'Action 3',
                        backgroundColor: '#111E6C',
                        borderColor: '#111E6C',
                        //backgroundColor: myColors_act3,
                        data: [0,0],
                        fill: false,
                        pointRadius: 5,
                        pointHoverRadius: 10,
                        showLine: true
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                hover: {
                    mode: 'point',
                    intersect: false
                },
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                legend: { position: 'right' },
                elements: {
                    point: {
                        pointStyle: 'circle',
                    },
                    line: {
                        tension: 0
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            callback: function (value) { if (value % 1 === 0) { return value; } },
                            suggestedMax: 4.1,
                            display: false //this will remove only the label
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{ gridLines: { display: false } }]
                }
            }
        });
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pXxqpp)

I tried to solve this by adding an x amount to all the values of the first dataset (eg 0.2) whereas on the the third dataset I did the same thing as in the first dataset but instead of adding I subtracted the same x amount.

Comment: Off topic for being subjective. However, I believe you should not modify the data. If the datasets are the same, make them _one series_. You can also use transparency to show when multiple series are overlaid. Finally you could switch to 3D visualisation, which would explicitly show multiple series as being same; Chart.js doesn't support 3D AFAIK, but I believe Plotly.js does.